# how to convert ES5 to ES6 in redux's reducer

Tags: redux

How to convert the below code to ES6: (especially the part after `newState.guests = []`

```
case ActionTypes.GetInviteFulfilled: {
   const { host, agenda, guests } = action.invite;
   const newState = Object.assign({}, state, {
      inProgress: false,
      success: 'Got invite.',
      host,
      agenda
    });
    newState.guests = [];
     if (guests) {
       newState.guests = Object.keys(guests).map(k => guests[k]);
     }
    return newState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
case ActionTypes.GetInviteFulfilled: {
  const { host, agenda, guests } = action.invite;
  return {
    ...state,
    inProgress: false,
    success: 'Got invite.',
    host,
    agenda,
    guests: guests ? Object.keys(guests).map(k => guests[k]) : [],
  };
}
```